# How to display the possible functions/variables imported from a go(lang) package in vim

Tags: go, vim

I am using vim 8+ with [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) and gopls. I have been able to get many of the features that and IDE would offer working such as importing packages on save, etc.

One behaviour I have not been able to replicate however is this the following...
[image]

The above is a screenshot taken from vscode showing a list of possible options available from the `fmt` package.

Would love to replicate this functionality, or something similar, in generic vim.

Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Comment: Are you running gopls?

Comment: Yeah. I have updated to question so include that now thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the "best" solution but this is something I managed to come up with making use of vim's [`omnicompletion`](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Omni_completion).

```
function AutoCompleter()
  let previousChar = getline('.')[col('.') - 2]
  if previousChar == '.'
    return "\<c-x>\<c-o>"
  else
    return "\<tab>"
  endif

  return ''
endfunction

inoremap <tab> <c-r>=AutoCompleter()<cr>
```

This solution creates a function which returns the keystrokes for `omnicompletion` if the previous character is a `.`.
Then I remap the `tab` key in insert mode to call this function.

This means that when I press tab in most cases it returns a tab, however, if I press tab after typing a `.` then I get the following...

[image]

In the above screenshot, this brings up the possible options from the `fmt` package. I can then use `CRTL` + `N`, `O` or `P` to navigate through the options.